# In an AST, should IF nodes have a huge amount of branches?

Tags: parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

Here's a picture of what I'm describing:
[image]
My question is, in an abstract syntax tree, should an IF node have a huge amount of branches? Imagine an IF node which is connected directly to hundreds of statements. It feels wrong and would look absolutely ridiculous in visual form. Is this the correct formation of an AST or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: Is this `if ((a>b) and (a=c))`? Is it `and` or an `or`? From where did you get get this image? This looks wrong. The AST of `if` is like `[if] [1:condition] [2:if-body/true-body] [3:else-body/false-body]`. See wiki [article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree#/media/File%3AAbstract_syntax_tree_for_Euclidean_algorithm.svg)

Comment: I made it. It's supposed to be: if (a > b) {a = c; fun(c); otherstuff} I was not sure how it should be so I asked this question... should the body be able to have hundreds of nodes connected to it from left to right in execution order, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way. This is also what you get when you use something like `CodeDOM`.

[image: AST of if (a > b) {a = c; fun(c); otherstuff}]

Practically `TrueBody` and `FalseBody` will each have one single child - `StatementGroup`. That in turn will have as many children as there are statements in that block. Similarly, if there are multiple `and`/`or` conditions, then `Condition` node will have one single node like say `AndCondition` with as many children as there are clauses.